# Polygon find the shortest way from start to end

Tags: c#, drawing

I am searching the shortest way in my polygon (route). It starts on the center border on bottom left (blue) and ends on the center border on the top right (red). It is not allowed to leave the route.

Which algorithm i can use to calculate this route? I need a list of points to draw the shortest way. A example code would be great.

[image: Example]

**Example of my polygon with start and end**

```
var points = new List<Point> { new Point(210, 540), new Point(330, 420), new Point(360, 420), new Point(420, 390), new Point(450, 330), new Point(480, 315), new Point(510, 270), new Point(570, 240), new Point(630, 240), new Point(690, 180), new Point(750, 150), new Point(810, 120), new Point(864, 120), new Point(864, 60), new Point(810, 60), new Point(750, 90), new Point(690, 120), new Point(630, 150), new Point(570, 150), new Point(510, 210), new Point(480, 255), new Point(450, 270), new Point(420, 330), new Point(360, 360), new Point(330, 360), new Point(156, 480) };

var image = new Bitmap(1000, 600);
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Blue, 190, 500, 10, 10, 0, 360);
    graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Red, 840, 80, 10, 10, 0, 360);
    graphics.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), points.ToArray());
}

image.Save("example.bmp");
```

Comment: A "simple" way can be to "place" your poligon in a virtual grid and use the A* algorithm to find the path.

Comment: I would go for a kind of [convex hull algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). If the path is complex it may be necessary to switch sides.

Comment: Have a look at the [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/animations/dijkstra.html)

Comment: One observation that constrains the problem: The shortest path between two points within an arbitrary polygon is a piecewise linear path where the vertices of the path will be the target endpoints or some of the concave vertices of the polygon (the vertices that point inwards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Thanks @gusman

- Add Raster
- Calculate distance between points
- Search best route with [Dijkstra.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dijkstra.NET/)

[image: Solution]

```
using Dijkstra.NET.Contract;
using Dijkstra.NET.Model;
using Dijkstra.NET.ShortestPath;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace Test.Polygon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var points = new List<Point> { new Point(210, 540), new Point(330, 420), new Point(360, 420), new Point(420, 390), new Point(450, 330), new Point(480, 315), new Point(510, 270), new Point(570, 240), new Point(630, 240), new Point(690, 180), new Point(750, 150), new Point(810, 120), new Point(864, 120), new Point(864, 60), new Point(810, 60), new Point(750, 90), new Point(690, 120), new Point(630, 150), new Point(570, 150), new Point(510, 210), new Point(480, 255), new Point(450, 270), new Point(420, 330), new Point(360, 360), new Point(330, 360), new Point(156, 480) };

            var start = new Point(190, 500);
            var target = new Point(840, 80);

            var image = new Bitmap(1000, 600);
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Blue, 190, 500, 10, 10, 0, 360);
                graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Red, 840, 80, 10, 10, 0, 360);
                graphics.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), points.ToArray());
            }

            var path = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);
            path.AddPolygon(points.ToArray());

            var pointsForConnect = DrawRaster(5, image, path);


            var dictionary = new Dictionary<uint, Point>();
            dictionary.Add(0, start);
            dictionary.Add(1, target);

            var graph = new Graph<int, string>();

            var i = 2;
            foreach (var point in pointsForConnect)
            {
                dictionary.Add((uint)i, point);
                graph.AddNode(i);
                i++;
            }

            foreach (var point in dictionary)
            {
                foreach (var point2 in dictionary)
                {
                    if (point.Equals(point2))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point2.Value.X - point.Value.X, 2) + Math.Pow(point2.Value.Y - point.Value.Y, 2));

                    if (dist > 50)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    graph.Connect(point.Key, point2.Key, (int)dist, null);
                    //graph.Connect()
                }
            }


            var dijkstra = new Dijkstra<int, string>(graph);
            IShortestPathResult result = dijkstra.Process(0, 1); //result contains the shortest path
            var shortestRouteIds = result.GetPath();

            var shortestRoutePoints = new List<Point>();
            foreach(var x in shortestRouteIds)
            {
                shortestRoutePoints.Add(dictionary[x]);
            }

            DrawDriver(shortestRoutePoints, image);

            image.Save("example.bmp");
        }

        private static void DrawDriver(List<Point> points, Bitmap image)
        {
            var pen = new Pen(Color.LightGreen, 5);

            for (var i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var x = points[i].X;
                var y = points[i].Y;

                var x1 = points[i + 1].X;
                var y1 = points[i + 1].Y;

                DrawLineInt(image, new Point(x, y), new Point(x1, y1), pen);
            }
        }

        private static void DrawLineInt(Bitmap bmp, Point p1, Point p2, Pen pen)
        {
            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                graphics.DrawLine(pen, p1.X, p1.Y, p2.X, p2.Y);
            }
        }

        private static List<Point> DrawRaster(int edge, Bitmap image, GraphicsPath path)
        {
            var points = new List<Point>();

            var countHorizontal = image.Width / edge;
            var countVertical = image.Height / edge;

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < countHorizontal; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < countVertical; y++)
                    {
                        var boxX = (x * edge) + (edge / 2);
                        var boxY = (y * edge) + (edge / 2);

                        if (!path.IsVisible(boxX, boxY))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        points.Add(new Point(boxX, boxY));

                        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightGray, x * edge, y * edge, edge, edge);
                    }
                }
            }

            return points;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like the shortest path. Assuming you start at the blue point: In the section between the first contact with the wall and the red point, the path shouldn't touch the wall for a second time. That part should be a straight line.

Comment: @gdir i think this is a problem with the raster, have you a example of the convex hul?

Comment: No, I don't have an off the shelf implementation for that problem. I have used convex hull algorithms for different problems, but the code doesn't fit for your problem. I would suggest to start with a straight line between the start and end point. Then check if the line intersects with one side of the wall. If yes, find the point on the side of the wall that has the greatest distance to the line. Then divide your path in two parts: Straight line from start point to point on wall and straight line from point on wall to end point. Then apply the same steps recursively on those two lines.